# Find and click a link with text - Coded UI

Tags: c#, hyperlink, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to create a test that finds a specified link on a web page and clicks it. What I am attempting to do is search for the link by specifying the name/text of the link. Is there a way to create a hyperlink object solely by specifying this?

I can do the following to find the link by specifying the href property like this:

```
     BrowserWindow browser = BrowserWindow.Locate("Window Title");
     var hyperlink = new HtmlHyperlink(browser);
     hyperlink.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlHyperlink.PropertyNames.Href, "link.com");
     Mouse.Click(hyperlink);
```

But I want to do the same thing by specifying the text/name of the link.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it...

This finds the link based on the text:

```
    hyperlink.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlHyperlink.PropertyNames.InnerText, "text");
```